# Yii1 gives following error. Php Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, yii

I am using yii1. I tried all possiblities. 
it gives me an error.

Php Warning: Creating default object from empty value

But i could not solve this error.
See my code. And tell me what is wrong here.

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk($id);
$user->setScenario('updateProfile');

$user->oldPassword = $user->password;
$user->password='';

$userDetails = PageOnFly::model()->findByPk($id);

***$userDetails->business_map_url = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/';***
```

$userDetails->business_map_url = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/';

// Error shows on above line, Please tell me what is wrong here

```
$userDetails->business_map_url.=strtolower($userDetails->state->state_iso).'/';

$userDetails->business_map_url .=str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($userDetails->city->city_short_name)).'/';

$userDetails->business_map_url .=$userDetails->map_url.'.html';

if(isset($_POST['User']) || isset($_POST['UserDetails']))
    {
        $user->attributes =  $_POST['User'];

        $userDetails->attributes = $_POST['PageOnFly'];

        $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();

        try
        {
            if($user->save())
            {
                if($userDetails->save())
                {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    $user->confirmPassword = '';
                    $user->password ='';
                    $user->currentPassword='';
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $transaction->rollback();
        }

    }



    $this->render('/businessProfile/_form',array('user'=>$user,'userDetails'=>$userDetails));
```

Please, suggest me what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could Be you are getting a wrong PageOnFly istance, probably the

```
PageOnFly::model()->findByPk($id);
```

not exist...for the `$id` value coudl be `user_id`

Comment: :- Thanks. Actually the $id was null